# Помогите сверстать элемент

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Я только начинаю, помогите сверстать элемент, мне нужно, чтобы при наведении на один из этих блоков, появлялся прямоугольник, как на картинке. Я так полагаю, можно сделать `div`, а потом ещё и `hover`, но может кто поможет легче сделать или же кто на [Codepen](https://codepen.io) видел такое исполнение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вы пробовали что-то сделать? По-моему вы уже достаточно сказали — `div` & `hover`.

Comment: Я пробовал, но ничего не вышло путного, создал по три блока и расположил их, а вот как через hover дальше сделать, не очень понимаю, я вот только расту, новичок

Comment: Добавил ответ, можете посмотреть. И помните, здесь не одобряют такого вида вопросы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если что то не ясно спрашивайте

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.items {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 30px auto;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.sub {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  display: none;
}

.item1 {
  background: red;
}

.item2 {
  background: green;
}

.item3 {
  background: blue;
}

.subitem1 {
  background: blue;
}

.subitem2 {
  background: red;
}

.subitem3 {
  background: green;
}

.item1:hover~.subitem2 {
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
}

.item2:hover~.subitem3 {
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
}

.item3:hover~.subitem1 {
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
}

p {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item item1"></div>
  <div class="item item2"></div>
  <div class="item item3"></div>

  <div class="sub subitem3"></div>
  <div class="sub subitem2"></div>
  <div class="sub subitem1"></div>
</div>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt, dolor praesentium soluta beatae asperiores vitae, nam nostrum obcaecati minus modi! Iusto aut deleniti velit libero ipsam quod, accusantium quia. Eos quos eum dolores dicta, nesciunt, debitis
  in harum pariatur a nisi impedit labore molestiae. Totam, placeat. Asperiores praesentium distinctio similique accusamus tempore, atque placeat quo veniam aperiam. Explicabo, possimus perferendis.
</p>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое вам, а можно ли как-нибудь сделать, чтобы когда наводишь, слитно было, а в это время от других блоков, отступ

Comment: @ОлегБорейко  обновил ответ ... так ?

Comment: Я про тот элемент, который появляется

Comment: @ОлегБорейко  опять обновил ответ - так ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, ну вот, всего лишь переменные использовал))

Comment: @Arthur  я же говорил !  :))

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, это я и ожидал=))

Comment: @Arthur  я тебя плюсанул -- дань уважения

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, необязательно, лучше с вопросом одним помоги в чате))

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78380/discussion-between---and-arthur).

Answer (score 4):

```css
:root {
  --size: 10rem;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.2rem;
  top: 100%;
  width: calc(var(--size) * 3.1);
  border: 1px solid;
  visibility: hidden;
}

ul {  
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.item {
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: var(--size);
  margin: 0.2rem;
}

.item:hover~.list {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="list">
      <ul>
        <li><a>link</a></li>
        <li><a>link</a></li>
        <li><a>link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="list">
      <ul>
        <li><a>link</a></li>
        <li><a>link</a></li>
        <li><a>link</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><a>link</a></li>
        <li><a>link</a></li>
        <li><a>link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="list">
      <ul>
        <li><a>link</a></li>
        <li><a>link</a></li>
        <li><a>link</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><a>link</a></li>
        <li><a>link</a></li>
        <li><a>link</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><a>link</a></li>
        <li><a>link</a></li>
        <li><a>link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: top 100% наверно надо было мм ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, разницы никакой, исправил, так и быть=)

Comment: это на случай если автор применит твой пример то при изменении высоты координата останется ..автор вопроса же я уверен о var и понятия не имеет :))

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, ну ничего, выучит))

Comment: давай хоть чуть чуть будем по дружелюбнее :))

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, это и есть дружелюбие, предсказал то, что вполне возможно. Когда-то ведь выучит=)